# Permission denied when working with/without "su -c" in /cache

Tags: root-access, terminal, 8.1-oreo

I am trying to issue this command

```
adb shell "su -c echo 'boot-recovery' > /cache/recovery/command"
//OR//
adb shell "echo 'boot-recovery' > /cache/recovery/command"
```

outputs the same: `/system/bin/sh: can't create /cache/recovery/command: Permission denied`

I granted root permission for adb and i can run other commands with root normally like `touch` for example

I tried the command both ways when the file did and did not existed.

I tried checking for the existence of the file:

```
adb shell "if [ -f /cache/recovery/command ]; then echo "file found"; else echo "error"; fi"
```

it returned `error` even though the file does in fact exist

**The Goal is** to add a few lines to the recovery queue so the run the next time the device boots into recovery

Please correct me, I'm not so good at android command line, do I need to use a different command to achieve this goal?

**More info:** Android 8.1 (RR oreo) ... Magisk SU ... TWRP 3.2 *(But need this to be compatible with as many android versions, recoveries, and su binaries as possbible .... **I hope lol**)*

Comment: It's better to Ask your question on [superuser community](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adb shell 'su -c "echo \"boot-recovery\" > /cache/recovery/command"'
adb shell 'su -c "'"echo "boot-recovery" > /cache/recovery/command"'"' #Alternative
adb shell "su -c \"echo 'boot-recovery' > /cache/recovery/command\"" #Another alternative
adb shell 'su -c "'"echo "'"boot-recovery"'" > /cache/recovery/command"'"' #yet another alternative
```

That should work. I'm not sure why. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/4720957) from codeforester might help you out if you're looking for a reason.

My take is that, in:

```
adb shell "su -c echo 'boot-recovery' > /cache/recovery/command"
```

adb shell launches a non-interactive shell, the double quotes are expanded  , leaving

```
su -c echo 'boot-recovery' > /cache/recovery/command
```

However, in this, only echo `'boot-recovery'` gets to be run with root privilege and the resulting output falls back to shell user (id=2000) which doesn't have the privilege to write into cache directory, hence the error.

Quoting everything after `-c` passes whole `echo 'boot-recovery' > /cache/recovery/command` instruction to `su` executable, and so, that does work.

Comment: Thanks for the info .. how to avoid getting it in the hands of the user and keep it in root mode...  **are the 4 commands you wrote a solution? because they output the same `Permission denied`**

Comment: I don't know why it outputs permission denied in your case. It works here. Does the shell/adb has permission to switch to root user in your superuser app?

Comment: in magisk su it lets apps and adb have root access... I will try to play with another option related to owner/user/something root access

Comment: omg.. The 2nd one of your commands worked after i changed the Multi-user mode from `Device Owner Only` to `User Independent`... and now i opened the `command` file, it has "boot-recovery" in it (success) ..... _It worked even tho powershell doesn't like it (it colors it wild)_

Comment: Sorry for commenting a lot.. Now i tested it it does write to `command` but nothing happens when booting into recovery, so the main goal is not achieved

Comment: @NHKomaiha it is an altogether different question, so please ask a new question. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Although it was my main goal to do the queue but ok.. at least i learned something useful here, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked:

```
adb shell "su -c 'boot-recovery > /cache/recovery/command'"
```

You start with a double quote before `su -c`. Then single quote for the command, a single quote after the command and close with a double quote.